# Issues installing addons for local EE3 installation (Error: Unable to load the requested language file)

Tags: add-on, ee3, addons

I've got a local installation of ExpressionEngine 3 and I'm trying to install an add-on to allow me to customise the control panel CSS.

I've tried the following add-ons but after installing and when trying to access the add-on in the control panel I'm presented with the following errors. It's done the same thing for both add-ons making me think it's not an issue with the add-ons:

> **https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/digi-nut-control-panel-css-js gave the following error:** *Error: Unable to load the requested language file:
> language/english/dn_control_panel_css_js_lang.php*
>
> **https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css gave the following error:** Error: Unable to load the requested language file:
> language/english/cpcss_lang.php

Any suggestions will be very welcome,

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing these module and it works fine at my end.

You can try go to both the paths and rename the files **lang.dn_control_panel_css_js.php** and **lang.cpcss.php**. There is less chances.

Comment: Interesting​, are you also working locally?

Comment: Nope. Local EE has its own list of problems